# Render components under root route not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a route path `/` that rendering `Home` component

`Home` component contain a list. every item should render a route `/:id`

So much paths will be `www.example/:id`

I would render lists content under home content.

My problem is that every time I click on a list item the list get disappeared and nothing is rendered.

```
function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Topics</h1>
      <ul>
        {topics.map(({ name, id }) => (
          <li key={id}>
            <Link to={`/${id}`}>{name}</Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>

      <hr />

      <Route path={`/:topicId`} component={Topic} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Topic() {
  return <div>TOPIC</div>;
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here's an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-routes-4-forked-k12bp?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of similar routes. we will deal with exact props. No need to reorder the routes.

```
<Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/:topicId" component={Topic} />
<Switch>
```

For more details, you can follow https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/exact-bool

Comment: Thanks but this way when I click on link this will disapear `Home` component that's not what I would . I need to keep it and show link content under the links list

Comment: @infodev so you can remove the exact and you'll get what you need

Comment: For nested routing, you can follow https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v6-pre/#introducing-routes

It will help you

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the exact, like so:

```
<Router>     
      <Route path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/:topicId" component={Topic} />
</Router>
```

Now your Home & Topic will appear

Comment: Check  my comment under @Dheeraj response

Comment: Thanks that's working ( I accepted other response because of response chronological order ) your's working too.